# Symfony : Can't get data from third table in ManyToMany relation

Tags: php, symfony, collections

I have a relation between the entities Product and FeatureValue. Doctrine added the usual getters and setters and created a third table named product_feature_value.

However, when I try to get the informations from my productrepository, no results are fetched.

On twig :
`{{ dump(product.featureValues) }}`

The result is empty :

````
    -owner: App\Entity\Product {#767 ▼
     [...]
    -featurevalues: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#853}
  }```

Is it possible to get the data without dql and only with the ProductRepository ?
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Symfony uses lazy loading, meaning that the result of the third table will be empty unless you explicitly ask for it.

So in twig, instead of `{{ dump(product.featureValues) }}` you will have to use a method e.g. : `{{ dump(product.featureValues.getValues) }}` or in the controller : `dd($product->getFeaturevalues()->getValues());`